# How to use axios within foreach?

Tags: javascript, foreach, axios

I want to use axios within foreach. When axios complete then foreach must go to the next step. But I can't do it. foreach go to the next step axios doesn't completed.

Comment: You can use custom recursive function and add axios inside it.. once axios request is completed call the function with next element.

Comment: Please give me code example pleease

Comment: check this https://developer-paradize.blogspot.com/2018/07/using-axios-in-loop-with-asyncawait.html

Comment: it doesn't work async